# Volume of a solid with an elliptical base

Tags: calculus, volume

> Find the volume $V$ of the described solid $S$.
>   The base of $S$ is an elliptical region with boundary curve $9x^2 + 25y^2 = 225$. Cross-sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis are isosceles right triangles with hypotenuse in the base.

I tried this:
$$\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{9}=1$$
$$A=\frac{1}{2}l^2(2y^2)=y^2$$
Solving for $y$ I got
$$y=\pm3\sqrt{4-x^2}$$
$$V=2\int_{0}^{2}3\sqrt{4-x^2}dx=6\pi$$
But this is wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: ...and you've answered your own question! (Wrongly.)

Comment: I put in the answer 6π and yes, it was wrong. What am I doing wrong with the setup of my volume equation before I take the integral? Or am I? I have spent hours trying to figure this out and was hoping one of you guys might have the time to help. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

We find
$$y=\pm3\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{25}}$$
For a given $x=a$, $y$ represents half the hypotenuse of the triangle built upon $x=a$, and the area of that triangle is $y^2$. Hence the volume of $S$ is
$$V=\int_{-5}^5y^2dx$$
$$=\int_{-5}^5\left(3\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{25}}\right)^2dx$$
$$=\int_{-5}^59\left(1-\frac{x^2}{25}\right)dx$$
$$=\frac9{25}\int_{-5}^5(25-x^2)dx$$
$$=\frac9{25}\left[25x-\frac{x^3}3\right]_{-5}^5$$
$$=\frac9{25}\left[\frac{250}3-\left(-\frac{250}3\right)\right]$$
$$=60$$